# request structure for multipart/form-data for restClient

Tags: json, rest

I have used Multipart Parser used to parse multipart/form-data on the server and now I want to test my API using RestClient (addon in firefox) and i need the request structure for that. 
Can Anyone help?

Comment: Why do you need the structure? Are you trying to write the raw request yourself? Does the client not support sending multipart requests? If not you can check out Postman for Chrome.

Comment: Just wanted to check the code for my API. I am using RestClient in firefox